# is it possible to obtain recursion value at runtime?

Tags: c, linux

I have a Fibonacci recursion function:

```
int efib (int num) {     
    if (num == 0){    
        return 0;
    }else if (num == 1){ 
        return 1;
    }else if (num == -1){ 
        return -1;
    }else if (num > 0){  
        return efib(num - 1) +  efib (num - 2);
    }else{    
        return efib (num + 1) + efib(num + 2);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find the exact element `num` where the `int` value overflows, is it possible to obtain the current recursion value to compare it to the maximum value an `int` data type can hold?

I know that the max value an int can hold that is included in the Fibonacci sequence is 1836311903.

Comment: Integer overflow causes undefined behavior, there's no portable way to detect it or continue after it.

Comment: You could do your arithmetic using `long` instead of `int`, and detect when the value is higher than `(long)INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find the exact element (num) where the int value overflows

To prevent overflow, pass the 2 operands to an [OF test function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93699/29485) before adding.

It use a "compare it to the most value an int data type can hold".

```
#include <limits.h>
int is_undefined_add1(int a, int b) {
  return (a < 0) ? (b < INT_MIN - a) : (b > INT_MAX - a);
}

   ....
   // return efib(num - 1) +  efib (num - 2);
   int a = efib(num - 1);
   int b = efib(num - 2);
   if (is_undefined_add1(a, b)) {
     fprintf(stderr, "fib[%d] was about to overflow\n", num);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   return a + b;
```

---

If a wider type (`long`, `long long` or `intmax_t`) is available, simple add via that type and check the sum against the `int` range. [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980045/is-it-possible-to-obtain-recursion-value-at-runtime/52980116#comment92866578_52980045)

```
#if LLONG_MAX/2 >= INT_MAX && LLONG_MIN/2 <= INT_MIN
int is_undefined_add1(int a, int b) {
  long long sum = a;
  sum += b;
  return sum < INT_MIN || sum > INT_MAX;
}
#else
  // as above
#endif
```